# How can I change color of date on the datepicker vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, vuetify.js

Demo codepen like this : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/pooeMpo?&editable=true&editors=101

I try this : `.v-date-picker-table .v-btn { color: green };` and it works

But my problem is I want to add conditions. so on a certain date, it is green. on other dates the color is black.

For example the color of odd date is green. even date is black

How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe you can get som inspiration from this answer:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738834/3163418](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738834/3163418)

Comment: @mapa0402 This case is datepicker on vuetify. Not others

Answer (score 2):

As per your question, you need to color the **specific dates** and highlight selected date color for these specific dates

By default vuetify gives :event-color="primary" :events="any function" to add additional style below the date, which doesn't deal with the dates color

> If you use color="green--text" it changes the color all the dates and
>   not ahve control for specific dates

Still you can add your own logic to set the **color for specific date**, based on  your need. But it requires some additional logic to handle this case

The below code considers, **available dates** amoung all dates and apply css to those dates programatically

> Find the working codepen here:
>   https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/LYYyNYd?editors=1010

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-date-picker v-model="picker" @change="dateClicked"></v-date-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>

.date-color {
  color: #00B300;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.v-btn--active .date-color {
  color: #fff;
}


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      picker: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      availableDates: ["2019-10-02", "2019-10-8", "2019-10-11"],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dateClicked(val) {
      var allDates = document.querySelectorAll(".v-date-picker-table .v-btn .v-btn__content");
      var dates = this.availableDates.map(x => parseInt(x.split('-')[2]));
      allDates.forEach((x, i) => {
        if (dates.includes(parseInt(val.split('-')[2])) && parseInt(val.split('-')[2]) == x.innerHTML) {

          x.parentNode.style = "background-color: #00b300 !important";
        } else {
          x.parentNode.style = '';
        }
      });

    },
    setColor() {
      var allDates = document.querySelectorAll(".v-date-picker-table .v-btn .v-btn__content");
      var dates = this.availableDates.map(x => parseInt(x.split('-')[2]));
      console.log(dates);
      allDates.forEach((x, i) => {
        if (dates.includes(parseInt(x.innerHTML))) {
          allDates[i].classList.add('date-color');
        }
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
  this.setColor();
}
})
```